# Determine margin between elements

Tags: html, css

Lets say i have 3 elements.

```
<h2>test<h2>
<h2 style="visibility: visible" >test1<h2>
<h2>test2<h2>
```

Now via java script i sometimes want to hide test1, thats no problem. but when that happens i want test2 right below test. At this moment when test1 is hiding there is an empty space between test and test2.
I tried to do it with changing the margin-top of test2 when test1 is hiding, but nothing happens.

```
  if (condition is true, change the margin-top of test2)
```

Comment: So why are you using visibility and not display:none????

Comment: #JBallin, yep i get it now, tx